# Override input value in Child component in React

Tags: reactjs, input, parent

I have a child input component and parent where I set value.

**Parent component**

```
const \[dummyText, setDummyText\] = useState('')
return (

<Input
  {...props}
  id="first-name"
  label="First name"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Please enter your first name"
  value={dummyText}
  onChange={(value) => setDummyText(value.target.value)}
/>
)
```

**Child input component**

```
    import React, { InputHTMLAttributes, forwardRef } from 'react'
    export type Props = {} & InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>

    const FormInput: React.FC<Props> = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Partial<Props>>(
      ({ ...props }, ref) => <input ref={ref} {...props} />
    )

    FormInput.displayName = 'FormInput'

    export default FormInput
```

I want to add button in child component where on click I need to clear the value.

The thing is that I want to have clear functionality in child component and I do not want to write extra code for every <Input in parent, and whatever I do in child component, I just can't override props.value.

Does anybody have any experience how to solve this?

Comment: Could you share your `Input` component?

Comment: @RubenSmn I have updated my code. Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clear the input value you can pass the clearing function as a prop to the child component like this:

```
const Input = ({ onClearInput, ...otherProps }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', gap: '.5rem' }}>
      <input {...otherProps} />
      <button onClick={onClearInput}>Clear</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [secondName, setSecondName] = useState('');

  const onClearInputHandler = (handler) => handler('');

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', gap: '.5rem' }}>
      <Input
        id="first-name"
        label="First name"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Please enter your first name"
        value={firstName}
        onChange={(event) => setFirstName(event.target.value)}
        onClearInput={() => onClearInputHandler(setFirstName)}
      />

      <Input
        id="second-name"
        label="Second name"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Please enter your second name"
        value={secondName}
        onChange={(event) => setSecondName(event.target.value)}
        onClearInput={() => onClearInputHandler(setSecondName)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Because you'll have a different state for each input you can pass the `set` function from `useState` as a parameter and run it inside the `onClearInputHandler` to clear the value.

**Edit:**
Then I think the easiest solutions is to handle the `clear` function inside the input itself like this:

```
  const Input = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.value || '');
  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', gap: '.5rem' }}>
      <input
        {...props}
        value={value}
        onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={() => setValue('')}>Clear</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const onSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(event.target);
    const formProps = Object.fromEntries(formData);
    console.log(formProps);
  };

  return (
    <form action="submit" onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', gap: '.5rem' }}>
        <Input
          id="first-name"
          label="First name"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Please enter your first name"
          name="first-name"
        />

        <Input
          id="second-name"
          label="Second name"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Please enter your second name"
          name="second-name"
        />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" style={{ margin: '.5rem 0' }}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
```

All inputs are inside the `form` and you can read the values when the form is submitted. Otherwise you'll have to create a new `state` or `ref` for every single `Input` you have in your parent component. This way the input value and the handler to clear it are always inside the `Input` component.

Here's a demo on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gnyvav?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: Tnx for the effort jcobo1. 
The thing is that, as I said, I want to have clear function inside Child component which overrides props.value. I want to avoid writing function in parent to every <Input usage, since clear is part of basic "setup" of our <Input component.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions for this, I came up with these two

#### onValueChange

Another solution might be to refactor the `onChange` to a `onValueChange` which instead of the `event` immediately returns the `value`.  Updated the type and removed the `Partial` since it was giving some errors.

```
type Props = {
  onValueChange: (value: string) => void;
} & InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>;

const FormInput: React.FC<Props> = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props>(
  ({ onValueChange, ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
      <>
        <input
          ref={ref}
          onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e.target.value)}
          {...props}
        />
        <button onClick={() => onValueChange("")}>clear</button>
      </>
    );
  }
);
```

A issue with this is that if a `onChange` is provided it will override the existing `onChange`. We can solve this by simply adding it and passing the `e` (event)

```
const FormInput: React.FC<Props> = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props>(
  ({ onValueChange, onChange, ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
      <>
        <input
          ref={ref}
          onChange={(e) => {
            onValueChange(e.target.value);
            onChange(e);
          }}
          {...props}
        />
        <button onClick={() => onValueChange("")}>clear</button>
      </>
    );
  }
);
```

Which you can then use by

```
<FormInput
  id="first-name"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Please enter your first name"
  value={dummyText}
  onValueChange={setDummyText}
  // onChange={(e) => console.log(e)}
/>
```

#### onClear

Now this does not fully move the functionality to the Input component.

We destructure the `onClear` function and add it to the `onClick` of the clear button.

```
type Props = { onClear: () => void } & InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>;

const FormInput: React.FC<Props> = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props>(
  ({ onClear, ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
      <>
        <input ref={ref} {...props} />
        <button onClick={onClear}>clear</button>
      </>
    );
  }
);
```

Now to use it you can go like this

```
<Input
  id="first-name"
  onClear={() => setDummyText("")}
  type="text"
  placeholder="Please enter your first name"
  value={dummyText}
  onChange={(event) => setDummyText(event.target.value)}
/>
```